# Sharing Folder Error with Ubuntu and SAMBA

Tags: samba

I have a home network working with an Ubuntu 16.04 server and Windows 10 clients. Actually, I share a folder with SAMBA and every thing works fine. In the file /etc/samba/smb.conf, I set it up like this:

`[ArquivosAL]
path = /home/administrador/ArquivosAL
read only = no
public = yes
browseable = yes
guest ok = yes
writable = yes
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777`

This week I installed a new HDD and I would like to share with the Windows clients as well. I include the following code in the smb.conf file:

`[ArquivosAuto]
path = /media/administrador/AL-Auto/ArquivosAuto
read only = no
public = yes
browseable = yes
guest ok = yes
writable = yes
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777`

The problem is that I can seen the folder on Windows client, but I **can't** access the files. I'm getting the error *"Windows cannot access \\SERVER-HP\ArquivosAuto"*.

Some one knows why? How can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permissions of /media/$USER ( /media/administrador in this case ) has an access control list imposed upon it by the system that allows only $USER ( administrador ) access.

One way around this issue is to change the mount point to be someplace else - even just one level up like `/media/AL-Auto`

Another way is to make the remote guest user appear to be "administrador" - at least for that share. You do that by editing the share definitions to look like this:

```
[ArquivosAuto]
path = /media/administrador/AL-Auto/ArquivosAuto
read only = no
public = yes
browseable = yes
guest ok = yes
writable = yes
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777
force user = administrador
```